# Application Crashes after adding Splash Screen

Tags: android, android-layout, android-intent, android-emulator

Hi i made a project which was running great before i started adding this Splash Screen to my project ..... I tried to check every possible thing ...But now my application does not even start . Moment i click on the icon to launch my application " Message comes up saying that Application has  stopped working and  needs to close" Please help

---

Androidmanifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="hellog.diwesh.NugaBest"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="10" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADMIN" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

    <application
        android:name="helog.diwesh.NugaBest.MyApplication" 
        android:debuggable="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/nuga"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <activity
            android:name="helog.diwesh.NugaBest.NUGA_HealthCareActivity_Intro"
            android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>





         <activity
            android:name="helog.diwesh.NugaBest.SplashActivity"
            android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="helog.diwesh.NugaBest.CLEARSCREEN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>






        // 4. Layout Management

        <activity
            android:name="helog.diwesh.NugaBest.FileSiganlDisplay"
            android:label="FileSiganlDisplay" />
        <activity
            android:name="helog.diwesh.NugaBest.NUGA_WebJoinActivity"
            android:label="NUGA_WebJoinActivity"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden" />
        <activity
            android:name="helog.diwesh.NugaBest.NUGA_MainMenuActivity"
            android:label="NUGA_MainMenuActivity" />
        <activity
            android:name="helog.diwesh.NugaBest.BTSmartSlavemodule"
            android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden"
            android:label="SmartSlavemodule" />
        <activity
            android:name="helog.diwesh.NugaBest.BTDeviceListActivity"
            android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden"
            android:label="@string/select_device"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Dialog" />

        <activity
            android:name="helog.diwesh.NugaBest.SnapActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_snap" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="helog.diwesh.NugaBest.ImagesActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_images" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="helog.diwesh.NugaBest.HelpActivity"
            android:label="@string/Help" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="helog.diwesh.NugaBest.AboutDevice"
            android:label="@string/aboutus" >
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

---

Intro.java : this was my first screen before

```
public class NUGA_HealthCareActivity_Intro extends Activity {

    SoundPool mpool;
    int mlogon;
    int mValue;
    ProgressDialog mProgress;

    TextView mAnimTarget1;
    EditText mAnimTarget2;
    TextView mAnimTarget3;
    EditText mAnimTarget4;
    Button mAnimTarget5;
    TextView mAnimTarget6;
    Button mAnimTarget7;
    ProgressBar mProgCircle;

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onDestroy();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onPause();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onResume();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onStart();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStop() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onStop();
    }

    Animation anim = null;

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        setContentView(R.layout.splash_screen);
        Thread logoTimer=new Thread(){

            public void run(){

                try
                {
                    int logoTimer=0;
                    while(logoTimer<5000){
                        sleep(100);
                        logoTimer=logoTimer+100;

                    }
                    startActivity(new Intent("helog.diwesh.NugaBest.CLEARSCREEN"));

                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

                finally{
                    finish();
                }
            }


        };

        logoTimer.start();


        Vibrator vibe = (Vibrator) getSystemService(Context.VIBRATOR_SERVICE);
        long[] pattern = { 0, 300, 100, 100, 100, 300, 300, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 0 };

        vibe.vibrate(pattern, -1);

        mAnimTarget1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.Tvpass);
        mAnimTarget2 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.EtID);
        mAnimTarget3 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.TvID);
        mAnimTarget4 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.Etpass);
        mAnimTarget5 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.BtnLogin);
        mAnimTarget6 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.Tvjoin);
        mAnimTarget7 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.BtnJoin);
        mProgCircle = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progcircle);

        findViewById(R.id.BtnLogin).setOnClickListener(mClickListener);
        findViewById(R.id.BtnJoin).setOnClickListener(mClickListener);

        mpool = new SoundPool(1, AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, 0);
        mlogon = mpool.load(this, R.raw.logon, 1);

        anim = new AlphaAnimation(0, 1);
        anim.setDuration(1500);

        mAnimTarget1.startAnimation(anim);
        mAnimTarget2.startAnimation(anim);
        mAnimTarget3.startAnimation(anim);
        mAnimTarget4.startAnimation(anim);
        mAnimTarget5.startAnimation(anim);
        mAnimTarget6.startAnimation(anim);
        mAnimTarget7.startAnimation(anim);
        mpool.play(mlogon, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1);

    }

    Button.OnClickListener mClickListener = new View.OnClickListener() {

        Animation anim = null;

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Vibrator vibe = (Vibrator) getSystemService(Context.VIBRATOR_SERVICE);
            vibe.vibrate(60);

            switch (v.getId()) {
            case R.id.BtnLogin:
                mpool.play(mlogon, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1);
                anim = new ScaleAnimation(0, 1, 0, 1, Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0.5f, Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0.5f);
                anim.setDuration(100);
                mAnimTarget5.startAnimation(anim);
                mProgCircle.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                mValue = 0;
                new AccumulateTask().execute(100);



                //Intent intent0 = new Intent(NUGA_HealthCareActivity_Intro.this, NUGA_MainMenuActivity.class);
                //startActivity(intent0);

                //finish();
                overridePendingTransition(R.anim.fade, R.anim.hold);

                break;

            case R.id.BtnJoin:

                mpool.play(mlogon, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1);
                anim = new ScaleAnimation(0, 1, 0, 1, Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0.5f, Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0.5f);
                anim.setDuration(100);
                mAnimTarget7.startAnimation(anim);
                mProgCircle.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

                Intent intent = new Intent(NUGA_HealthCareActivity_Intro.this, NUGA_WebJoinActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent);

                overridePendingTransition(R.anim.zoom_enter, R.anim.zoom_exit);

                break;

            default:
                break;
            }

        }
    };

    class AccumulateTask extends AsyncTask<Integer, Integer, Integer> {
        private String title = "Thank you for your patience";
        private String msg = "Loading";

        protected void onPreExecute() {
            mValue = 0;

            mProgress = new ProgressDialog(NUGA_HealthCareActivity_Intro.this);
            mProgress.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_HORIZONTAL);
            mProgress.setTitle(title);
            mProgress.setMessage(msg);
            mProgress.setCancelable(false);
            mProgress.setProgress(0);

            mProgress.setButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {
                    cancel(true);
                }
            });
            mProgress.show();
        }

        protected Integer doInBackground(Integer... arg0) {
            while (isCancelled() == false) {
                mValue++;
                if (mValue <= 100) {
                    publishProgress(mValue);
                } else {
                    break;
                }
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(40);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    ;
                }
            }
            return mValue;
        }

        protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... progress) {

            if (mValue == 30) {
                title = "Initializing";
                msg = "Please Wait";
                mProgress.setTitle(title);
                mProgress.setMessage(msg);
            }
            if (mValue == 75) {
                title = "Initializing";
                msg = "Extracting, Finalizing";
                mProgress.setTitle(title);
                mProgress.setMessage(msg);
            }

            mProgress.setProgress(progress[0]);

        }

        protected void onPostExecute(Integer result) {
            mProgress.dismiss();
            mProgCircle.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            // 
            Intent intent = new Intent(NUGA_HealthCareActivity_Intro.this, NUGA_MainMenuActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);

            finish();
            overridePendingTransition(R.anim.fade, R.anim.hold);
            // overridePendingTransition(R.anim.zoom_enter, R.anim.zoom_exit);
        }

        protected void onCancelled() {
            mProgress.dismiss();
            mProgCircle.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            Vibrator vibe = (Vibrator) getSystemService(Context.VIBRATOR_SERVICE);
            vibe.vibrate(60);
        }
    }

    public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
        super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
        String LOGTAG = null;
        Log.i(LOGTAG, "=== onConfigurationChanged is called !!! ===");

        if (newConfig.orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT) {                                                                          // ÀüÈ¯½Ã

            Log.i(LOGTAG, "=== Configuration.ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT !!! ===");
        } else if (newConfig.orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE) { 


            setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT); 
            Log.i(LOGTAG, "=== Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE !!! ===");
        }
    }
```

---

SplashActivity.java This is what i added and gave reference to intro.xml which was my layout for the previous Intro java class

```
import hellog.diwesh.NugaBest.R;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;

public class SplashActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.intro);

}

}
```

---

Here are the logCat details

```
09-11 22:27:35.304: D/dalvikvm(800): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 71K, 7% free 2543K/2732K, paused 139ms, total 149ms
09-11 22:27:35.374: I/dalvikvm-heap(800): Grow heap (frag case) to 5.455MB for 2998216-byte allocation
09-11 22:27:35.464: D/dalvikvm(800): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed <1K, 4% free 5471K/5660K, paused 87ms, total 87ms
09-11 22:27:36.034: D/AndroidRuntime(800): Shutting down VM
09-11 22:27:36.034: W/dalvikvm(800): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x41465700)
09-11 22:27:36.044: E/AndroidRuntime(800): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
09-11 22:27:36.044: E/AndroidRuntime(800): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{hellog.diwesh.NugaBest/helog.diwesh.NugaBest.NUGA_HealthCareActivity_Intro}: java.lang.NullPointerException
09-11 22:27:36.044: E/AndroidRuntime(800):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2211)
09-11 22:27:36.044: E/AndroidRuntime(800):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2261)
09-11 22:27:36.044: E/AndroidRuntime(800):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)
09-11 22:27:36.044: E/AndroidRuntime(800):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1256)
09-11 22:27:36.044: E/AndroidRuntime(800):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
09-11 22:27:36.044: E/AndroidRuntime(800):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
09-11 22:27:36.044: E/AndroidRuntime(800):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5103)
09-11 22:27:36.044: E/AndroidRuntime(800):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
09-11 22:27:36.044: E/AndroidRuntime(800):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
09-11 22:27:36.044: E/AndroidRuntime(800):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:737)
09-11 22:27:36.044: E/AndroidRuntime(800):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
09-11 22:27:36.044: E/AndroidRuntime(800):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
09-11 22:27:36.044: E/AndroidRuntime(800): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
09-11 22:27:36.044: E/AndroidRuntime(800):  at helog.diwesh.NugaBest.NUGA_HealthCareActivity_Intro.onCreate(NUGA_HealthCareActivity_Intro.java:129)
09-11 22:27:36.044: E/AndroidRuntime(800):  at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5133)
09-11 22:27:36.044: E/AndroidRuntime(800):  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
09-11 22:27:36.044: E/AndroidRuntime(800):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2175)
09-11 22:27:36.044: E/AndroidRuntime(800):  ... 11 more
09-11 22:27:42.604: D/dalvikvm(822): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 36K, 6% free 2543K/2696K, paused 96ms, total 144ms
09-11 22:27:42.644: I/dalvikvm-heap(822): Grow heap (frag case) to 5.455MB for 2998216-byte allocation
09-11 22:27:42.724: D/dalvikvm(822): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed <1K, 3% free 5471K/5624K, paused 78ms, total 78ms
09-11 22:27:43.464: D/AndroidRuntime(822): Shutting down VM
09-11 22:27:43.464: W/dalvikvm(822): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x41465700)
09-11 22:27:43.474: E/AndroidRuntime(822): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
09-11 22:27:43.474: E/AndroidRuntime(822): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{hellog.diwesh.NugaBest/helog.diwesh.NugaBest.NUGA_HealthCareActivity_Intro}: java.lang.NullPointerException
09-11 22:27:43.474: E/AndroidRuntime(822):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2211)
09-11 22:27:43.474: E/AndroidRuntime(822):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2261)
09-11 22:27:43.474: E/AndroidRuntime(822):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)
09-11 22:27:43.474: E/AndroidRuntime(822):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1256)
09-11 22:27:43.474: E/AndroidRuntime(822):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
09-11 22:27:43.474: E/AndroidRuntime(822):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
09-11 22:27:43.474: E/AndroidRuntime(822):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5103)
09-11 22:27:43.474: E/AndroidRuntime(822):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
09-11 22:27:43.474: E/AndroidRuntime(822):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
09-11 22:27:43.474: E/AndroidRuntime(822):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:737)
09-11 22:27:43.474: E/AndroidRuntime(822):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
09-11 22:27:43.474: E/AndroidRuntime(822):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
09-11 22:27:43.474: E/AndroidRuntime(822): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
09-11 22:27:43.474: E/AndroidRuntime(822):  at helog.diwesh.NugaBest.NUGA_HealthCareActivity_Intro.onCreate(NUGA_HealthCareActivity_Intro.java:129)
09-11 22:27:43.474: E/AndroidRuntime(822):  at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5133)
09-11 22:27:43.474: E/AndroidRuntime(822):  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
09-11 22:27:43.474: E/AndroidRuntime(822):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2175)
09-11 22:27:43.474: E/AndroidRuntime(822):  ... 11 more
```

---

I have this MyApplication.java too which is also there mentioned in the manifest ... is this interrupting somewhere ?

```
public class MyApplication extends Application {

    private static Context context;

    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        MyApplication.context = getApplicationContext();
    }

    public static Context getAppContext() {
        return MyApplication.context;
    }

}
```

---

Comment: Post your logcat error

Comment: `Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException` Post the `onCreate()` of `NUGA_HealthCareActivity_Intro`. AND Please have a proper naming of your java classes

Comment: I already did pasted the Logcat and the onCreate()

Answer (score 1):

Look in your manifest.  Change this line (located under your .SplashActivity insert):

```
<category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
```

to be this:

```
<category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
```

Then change the android.intent.category.LAUNCHER under your .helog.diwesh.NugaBest.NUGA_HealthCareActivity_Introclass to be this:

```
<category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
```

This will tell enable the SPLASH page to be the first page to display when your App is launched.

Comment: I did ... am not sure what happens but now it shows in logcat that it has  installed my .apk but i dont see my applicaation anywhere

Comment: Is the Splash code that you have displaying your current code?  If so, it isn't telling your application to proceed to the next activity.  Make sure that is coded as well.  Then once you see the Splash launch, run, and proceed, you may get a better idea of what is going bump.

Comment: No my current code is in the intro and  then the main menu ... this is just supposed to be the splash screen

Answer (score 0):

There is  Null pointer exception is coming as per attached logs ...
So please check 129 line in your source code.
Surely in this line you are to access some property of a NULL object

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
09-11 22:27:36.044: E/AndroidRuntime(800):  at helog.diwesh.NugaBest.NUGA_HealthCareActivity_Intro.onCreate(**NUGA_HealthCareActivity_Intro.java:129)**
09-11 22:27:36.044: E/AndroidRuntime(800):  at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5133)
```